# "Share on facebook" opens my app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

My iOS app integrates Facebook login, and everything works fine within the app.
The problem starts when somebody tries to share something to Facebook using another app (say, Instagram) - in some cases, the attempt to share just opens my app.

I tried to find references to similar bugs online and couldn't. Did anyone encounter something similar?

The app is written in Swift, and integrates FBSDKCoreKit 4.10.1, FBSDKLoginKit 4.10.1.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your projects `Info.plist` file for `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` parameter.

Comment: It is defined just as requested in the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: What to you have in your `URL types` in your `.plist` file related with this issue?